# GUI to monitor Akka standalone application?

Tags: java, scala, akka, monitoring, actor

We need a GUI to monitor the actors and mailbox queues for our Akka standalone application in production environment. This is my first Akka application; please let me know what my options are.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start evaluating the tools listed at [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=akka%20monitoring)?

Comment: I did. I found some that require a web container (in their tutorials). How can I use it for the standalone?